# Symfony can't find environment variable in the secrets

Tags: php, symfony5

I have the same problem as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016442/symfony-cant-find-secret-environment-variable).

Followed [Symfony Secrets Docu](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html) exactly as described.

1. Generated the keys.
2. Created the secret variable - `php bin/console secrets:set APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY`
3. The variable is there with the right value - `php bin/console secrets:list --reveal`
4. Added the following parameter to services.yaml
   `parameters: myapp.application_secret_key: '%env(APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY)%'`
5. Trying to access the key from the controller by - 
   `$apiSecret = $this->getParameter('myapp.application_secret_key');`

which results in an "not found" exception:

> Environment variable not found: "APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY".

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Same here, the only way is working for me is when overriding secrets locally https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html#local-secrets-overriding-secrets-locally but this is not solution. Maybe someone can figure out what is going on.